# Can no longer find Firefox spell check personal database in Firefox 3

Tags: firefox, spell-check, dictionary

I have [Ubuntu 8.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_8.04_LTS_.28Hardy_Heron.29) LTS (Hardy Heron) with Firefox 3.6.3. Unfortunately it is super easy to accidentally click *Add To Dictionary* on a word you do not want added into one's personal dictionary used in Firefox.

How do I remove the word 'intsead' out of it? I tried some tutorials on the web that said to find ~/.mozilla/*.default/persdict.dat, but I could not see one. As well, others have complained that this file no longer exists in Firefox 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the file sometimes takes a little while to be created if it was not there originally. After I waited about 5 minutes, the file popped into the folder and sure enough I found 'intsead' in there. I used 'vi' to edit it, used "dd" to remove that line, and then ":wq!" to save the file and leave the vi editor. All was well again.